# Substring Grouping Characters

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use substring to pull characters to compare to different times. The first time I'm using is the system time and I'm  only using HH:mm. The second time I'm pulling is from a text file, the line it grabs looks something like this:

03182016 21:35:02  ######## END  ########

I tried just using

convert = line.Substring(9,14); //Which I thought would give me 21:35, but it actually produces 21:25:02 ####.

If I understand properly, it's grouping the numbers with the colons, as Substring(9,9) gives 21:35:02. I can't alter the text file, how can I pull the first 5 numbers(21:35)?

Comment: Why not split on a space and take the second item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a Regular Expression:

```
        Regex rg = new Regex(@"\d{2}:\d{2}");
        string line = "03182016 21:35:02 ######## END ########";

        string time = string.Empty;
        if(rg.IsMatch(line))
            time = rg.Match(line).Value;
```

This is based on the line format you provided.

Cheers

Comment: @downvoter: could you at least substantiate your downvote?

Comment: I never would have thought to do it this way. The format NEVER changes, so this is by far the best option to me. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MarshalAlessi you're welcome. Please don't forget to mark the answer your prefer most.

Comment: As to the downvoter, the code works perfectly. To anyone else needing similar help with this question, this solution worked for me and is perfect for formatted pickings.

Answer (score 5):

I think substring's second parameter is the length of the substring in characters, not the end-position.  As written, the command

```
convert = line.Substring(9,14);
```

will pull the first 14 characters from the 9th position (starting from 0), which is why you get the #### symbols.  If you want 21:35, try

```
convert = line.Substring(9,5);
```

4 characters for the hh and mm, and 1 character for the colon.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument is the length, not the end position. So `line.Substring(9, 5)` would do.

To make your code less error-prone, I should suggest to `Split` on a space and take the second item.

Answer (score 0):

```
convert = line.Substring(9, 5);
```

Comment: While this answer may technically be correct, it's best to include an explanation with it.